# how big is GCM resistration id

Tags: android, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging

I haven't been able to find any documentation on the size and characteristics of the GCM Registration id.  What is the max size?  Can it be unicode?  I want to store this into a Microsoft Sql Server database and I need the specs on the field.

I have seen answers on other forums/threads but they are all different

Thanks,

Gary

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The length of the registration ID is not constant. According to what I've read, its limit is 4096 bytes. However, in practice, all the registration IDs I've seen were much shorter (around 100-200 bytes).

The characters I've seen used in the registration ID are `a` to `z`, `A` to `Z`, `0` to `9`, `-` and `_`. You can store it in any string/character/varchar column.

Comment: This is the kind of answer I have been seeing when looking around.  Am I the only one that is amazed that Google can't/won't define the data elements issued by their services?  All of the developers using their services are forced to guess based on observation.  Seems very unprofessional, no?

Comment: @DeanBlakely The official max length is 4096 bytes. You can use that without having to guess.

Comment: 4096 bytes translates to a field length of 512 characters, correct??

Comment: @Alchete no, the best you can do is 6 bits per character in b64 encoding.  This would require at most 3072 bytes.